# Fork a repo and rename personal copy, but still pull request to the same repo

Tags: git, github, repository, fork, pull-request

I have made a [personal copy](https://github.com/blue-ice/3D_Models) of [SparkFun's 3D_Models repository](https://github.com/sparkfun/3D_Models), and I want to make my own 3-D model repository (it will contain non-SparkFun parts that I CAD). However, it looks awkward having two repositories in my account named something like "3D Models", and I would like to rename the SparkFun repository to "SparkFun-3D-Models".

However, I'm concerned about renaming the SparkFun repository and submitting a pull request. Will that change the name of the repository in SparkFun's library as well? Do I need to modify the upstream link?

**What do I need to do on the command line to rename my version of SparkFun's repository and still be able to submit pull requests?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of searching, I found how to change the personal branch name, but still be able to pull request to the original repo:

1. Click the "Fork" button online on the project to you want to fork.
2. Go to `https://github.com/<your-username>/<cloned-repo-name>/settings` and rename the repo.
3. We need to grab the entire repository, selecting the branch needed and the local location that should be used: `git clone -b <branch-name> git@github.com:<your-username>/<renamed-repo-name>.git ~/git-repositories/<renamed-repo-name>`
4. `cd <repo-name>`
5. Add a new upstream: `git remote add upstream https://github.com/<forked-user>/<forked-repo-name>.git`
6. `git push -u origin master`

From my [git workflow](https://gist.github.com/blue-ice/4a94fc06859dd9f1b586).